# Adding custom logic in drools decision table

Tags: java, drools

[image]I am trying to call a custom function in my decision table in drools.
I have an object called myObject. I have a condition where I need to check

```
abs(myObject.totalDepth - myObject.bitDepth) > 200
```

Under the CONDITION in drools, I am trying

```
abs(myObject.totalDepth - myObject.bitDepth) > $1
```

I have also tried

[image]

I am getting error :

> unable to analyse custom logic.

Can someone help me on how do I write custom logic in drools decision table.

Comment: You seem to have deleted your image URL so it can't be displayed.

Comment: I was unable to add image.

Comment: You don't have enough rep to embed the image but you can link it and a higher rep user can embed it for you. If you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68086152/edit) your question, you can use the "add image" wizard or even put the imgur link raw. Unfortunately images are the only way to really see what your rules are for decision-table questions since they're spreadsheets. Without the image, I have no idea what `$1` is refering to in the code you've indicated you're using.

Comment: It gives me this error.
You need at least 10 reputation to post images

Comment: OK now you've got 19 reputation ^_^

Comment: Uploaded the image now. Thanks :)